# How to find the first derivative of the Moment generating function (MGF) in R for Gamma distribution?

Tags: r, probability-density, differentiation, gamma-distribution

The moment generating function (MGF) for `Gamma(2,1)` for given `t = 0.2` can be obtained using following `r` function.

```
library(rmutil)
gam_shape = 2
gam_scale = 1
t = 0.20
Mgf = function(x) exp(t * x) * dgamma(x, gam_shape, gam_scale)
int = integrate(Mgf, 0, Inf)
int$value
```

I want to find the first derivative of the MGF. I tried taking the derivative of the function `Mgf`, but I am getting errors. Please let me know if you have any different ways to find the first derivative of MGF.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: @Rohit  Here is what I have `f=expression(Mgf)
g = D(Mgf,'t')
int1 = integrate(g, 0, Inf)
int1$value` But I am getting errors. Thanks

Comment: Why are you integrating if you want the derivative?

Comment: @Rohit I want to find the value of the first derivative of the MGF. Thanks.